# Redirect response of Android Simulator running a locally hosted website to a localhost proxy server

Tags: android, proxy, localhost, simulator, proxy-server

I am running a locally hosted website in an Android Simulator browser by giving adequate proxy settings. Now i wish to setup a proxy server running on my local machine between Android browser and Web Server.

I tried to give my IP Address in Android settings, but website would not open in browser then. How should i go about it?

Comment: @Rajesh
Let me clear the whole scenario here:
-I am hosting a website in JBOSS using Eclipse
-I am able to access it in Android browser
-I am running a proxy server in Jmeter tool
-I want response of browser to pass through this proxy server

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, using the IP **10.0.2.2** in the Android Emulator will point to the PC it is running on.

Comment: I am able to run locally hosted website in android browser.

Answer (score 0):

once try with both IP Address (192.168.*.*) and with the ServerName i,e LocalHost

if it default port means No need to mention, it not mention the port.